# Localisation of values in JSON-LD

Tags: json-ld

I'm trying to work out the best way to handle localisation in JSON-LD. The spec has information on [String Internationalization](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#h3_string-internationalization) that allows you to specify different translations for string values:

```
{
  "@context":
  {
    ...
    "occupation": { "@id": "ex:occupation", "@container": "@language" }
  },
  "name": "Yagyū Muneyoshi",
  "occupation":
  {
    "ja": "忍者",
    "en": "Ninja",
    "cs": "Nindža"
  }
  ...
}
```

This covers translation but not internationalization where the content changes depending on locale.

E.g.

```
{
  "@context":
  {
    "@id": "http://example.org/carousel#mycarousel",
    "@language": "ja"
    ...
  },
  "slides": ["http://example.org/japan.jpg"]
}


{
  "@context":
  {
    "@id": "http://example.org/carousel#mycarousel",
    "@language": "es"
    ...
  },
  "slides": ["http://example.org/spain.jpg"]
}
```

Does anyone know if the above is invalid in the JSON-LD spec, i.e. having different field values depending on the @language while there @ids are the same? If not is there an alternate approach that could work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the above is invalid. `@language` is only used to annotate strings with their language. What you are looking for is higher-level information. As such, you need to use some vocabulary. Schema.org for instance has http://schema.org/inLanguage for this. There exist various others as well. Which one you want to use, depends on the specific use case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and I can see you are an authority on JSON-LD :)